# json parse returning null

Tags: json, web-services, parsing

i am trying to parse some json for the first time. My json looks like this:

{"categoryid":"2","accountid":"1","title":"Bed for sale","price":"2.99","description":"brand new bed ....}]

I've been trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

However, his JSON looks like:

{"paging":{"page":1,"total":123,"page_size":20,"pages":7},"loans":[{"id":519535,"name":"Oyunbat","description":{"languages": ....

The code in the tutorial expects the objectID "loans" however the JSON i'm attempting to parse does not have this objectID. It just has the value/key pairs.

My problem seems to be with this part of the code:

```
NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Where the dictionary is placed into an array. But since i do not have this objectID in my JSON i am getting a null returned and no data.

How can i do just a simple parse of the JSON i have by putting into an array?

Thank you very much for any help! I'm new to this and trying to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a root and child. Try this:

```
dict = [resp objectForKey:@"paging"]; 
  if( ( dict == nil ) || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) { 
NSLog( @"WARNING: %@", [dict description]); 
  return; 
 } 

 Title = [[dict objectForKey:@"title"]copy];

 NSLog(@"Your Value: %@", Title);
```

Comment: Thank you iDev. Actually, i was able to update the JSON to include the object ID in front. So now my jSON looks like: {"Items":[{"categoryid":2,"accountid":1,"title":"Bed for sale","price":"2.99","description":"brand new bed...}]. However, i am still getting a null return. This JSON works just fine: {"paging":{"page":1,"total":123,"page_size":20,"pages":7},"loans":[{"id":519535,"name":"Oyunbat","description":{"languages": ....}]

Comment: My code is as follows: - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                          
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    
    NSArray* itemList = [json objectForKey:@"Items"]; //2
    
    NSLog(@"Items: %@", itemList); //3
    
    // 1) Get the latest loan
    NSDictionary* item = [itemList objectAtIndex:0];